# Is it possible to create extended partition in MBR disk through disk management utility?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, disk-management

After creating primary partition I want to create logical drives on my Windows 7 machine. For that, we first need to create extended partition in Windows. I'm able to create extended partition on my MBR disk through fdisk (command line utility when we boot in DOS mode) or diskpart (command line utility after booting windows 7). But I don't see any option to create extended partition in disk management console as shown in the snapshot below:

[image]

Am I missing something or it is not a possibility from disk management?

Comment: Click on "new simple volume"?

Comment: That options and the wizard there after results in creation of another primary partition. I need an extended partition.

Comment: You need to create a primary partition to put your extended partitions in. I don't know how that tool works. I highly recommend to use something like GParted. Also make a backup of your data before even touching this stuff.

Comment: I guess Windows creates "simple volumes" as three primary partitions first, only then an extended partition will be created to hold additional "simple volumes" as logical partitions. I'm not sure though, I'm (almost) Linux-only now. The question just rings the bell from "my previous Windows life". If I'm recalling it right then this is one of many reasons I have abandoned Windows as "the OS which knows better what I want to do". I may be very wrong, I cannot confirm my guess at the moment, so I'm posting this as a comment only.

Comment: Oh! To confirm my claim try to create three more "simple volumes". The last one should be created in an extended partition. Then delete the previous two and expand/move the extended partition as you need. I'm still not sure it will work. If you can, go with GParted.

Comment: I seem to remember it asking you whether you wanted a primary or extended partition after that, but they do keep making each release of windows worse than the previous one and I gave up on using it several years ago.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you were right. I got it now. First 3 were created automatically as primary partitions. On 4th attempt while going through "Simple Volume" wizard it created an extended partition (with one logical drive inside it). Now I also understood the limitation of 4 maximum allowed partitions in MBR disks. It is 3 (Primary Paritions) + 1 (Extended parition). You might want to add this as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: yes, it is possible** to create an *extended partition*; but it is done only when the system wants it, the user's needs are irrelevant.

MBR partition table can hold up to four *primary partitions*; or up to three *primary partitions* and one *extended partition*. Only in the latter case one can create more and more partitions i.e. *logical partitions* inside the *extended* one.

It seems like Microsoft wanted to make it easy for inexperienced users who don't know about MBR limitations. Disk Management creates "simple volumes" as three *primary partitions* first, only then an *extended partition* will be created to hold additional "simple volumes" as *logical partitions*. This way the user is never stuck with four *primary partitions* – the situation that makes adding a 5th partition hard (it would require some precise operations on the partition(s), filesystem(s) and the partition table to convert one of the *primary partitions* into *logical partition* inside an *extended partition* – possible but somewhat risky, time consuming etc.).

According to the user *psusi*'s comment there were versions of Windows with Disk Management asking whether you want a *primary* or *extended partition*. I cannot confirm that. Nevertheless it doesn't matter in your case.

**There is a way to do what you want.** Create three more "simple volumes". The last one should be automatically created in an *extended partition*. Then delete the previous two and expand/move the *extended partition* as you need. In my opinion this solution is not a useful one – **it makes an easy task complex and time consuming without a good reason.**

**To keep it easy use another tool** (like `fdisk` and `diskpart` you have already mentioned; or third party software, e.g. *GParted*).